# Python: Cannot import from custom module

Tags: python, html

I am having an issue with python not being able to find or import my module. I am unsure how to fix this problem. My py file I'm trying to get my import into is in 'main' folder, the file I'm trying to import is one level up. My program is a package:

[Error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2II5.png)

[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5qVE.png)

Comment: Have you tried, `from models import Entry`?

Comment: `from models import Entry` gives me this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

Answer (score 0):

Trying copying your .py file to **site-packages** folder present in the Python folder and then running your python file from command prompt(`python -m <your_file_name>.py`)/python launcher/IDE. In case you are still getting the error then share your code as well so that people can see.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still very new at this and need a little more hand holding. I'm just confirming that the file I copied into my site-packages folder is my models.py file (the file I'm trying to import). When I go into my terminal window (which has the virtual environment activated) I type 'python -m run.py'? run.py is to run my entire program. I'm getting an error "Error while finding module specification..." Or was I suppose to type: python -m run.py/python launcher/IDE? The error that returns is "ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on 'run' while trying to find 'run.py/python')"

Comment: Could you please share your python file?

Comment: https://github.com/kevinli15/kombucha Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: In your route.py there was "~" symbol in one of the routes. After fixing that I believe it will get fixed.

Comment: I must have added that by mistake when I was trying to fix it, but no removing didn't solve the problem, still unable to import